# How to nest files by path segment in VS 2017 for ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to nest files by `pathSegment` in Visual Studio 2017 for ASP.NET Core project.

I added `.filenesting.json` file to solution folder with content:

```
{
    "help": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866610",
    "root": true,   //Also tried with false

    "dependentFileProviders": {
        "add": {
            "pathSegment": {}
        }
    }
}
```

but it's not working even when restarting VS. I think it should work, based on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2017#the-pathsegment-provider).

Not sure if file nesting should be enabled or disabled.
Problem is I can not see solution settings in dropdown:

[image: screenshot]

but it is under edit:

[image: screenshot 2]

I also tried with custom setting (not solution) and it also doesn't work. What did I miss?

Answer (score 8):

I think the documentation is wrong here - that screenshot is missing the actual rules. I dug into it for Stack Overflow and hit the same thing...here's what actually works for your case in `.filenesting.json`:

```
{
  "help": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866610",
  "root": true,
  "dependentFileProviders": {
    "add": {
      "pathSegment": {
        "add": {
          "Help.*": [ ".cs" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only important diff (AFAIK) is the actual rule `"add"` itself.